# Integrate private files for open source application code in devops pipeline

Tags: git, docker, private, devops

I have a Java Application that serves as the Backend to our entire project and all of our software is fully open source. The problem is as follows:

We use several API keys from Google, SendGrid to MySQL Database authentication keys. All of these are stored in the `application.properties` file. The code we have on GitHub is ditto except that these files are missing. The workaround currently is they are only available on the Heroku remote through which we deploy to Heroku. Whenever we wish to deploy a change, we switch to the heroku branch, pull changes from master and rebase this branch and finally push it.

We're soon shifting to [cycle.io](https://cycle.io) runs containerized applications, so basically we're shifting to [Docker](https://docker.com). We're going to have the appliation dockerized and a MySQL Docker instance deployed and communicating with each other. To quote from Cycle

> An environment allows you to organize and communicate between your
>   containers. When you click 'start' on a container from the enviroment,
>   the networking automatically configures, and notify any other
>   containers within the environment of its presence.

Cycle.io allows us to automatically link either images from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com) or have a git repository with a `Dockerfile`. It picks it up from there and then automatically deploys it.

**My Question is, how do I integrate this private files in my code-build-test-deploy pipeline?**. Naively, I was thinking of some way that'injects' these files before building. I have no clue how to do so. My current idea for docker deployment was

- Build a docker image on my local system that works
- Push it to Docker Hub to a private repository and allow cycle.io, which integrates with docker hub to pick it up from there
- (I wanna integrate Tavis/CI too, idk how)

Is there any *SENSIBLE*, or for the lack of another word, *PRO* way of doing this? We're a group of students looking to follow best practices and this application is going to scale big. We've gotten ourselves fully paid for deployment and domain name passes etc already but we don't really have any expert guidance.

Comment: You can't do this properly unless cycle.io lets you configure *some kind* of secret data for your environment.  Given that, it's easy to leverage into larger secrets.  It could be an encryption key necessary to decrypt local files, a password required to access a database, etc.  Without some kind of support from cycle.io, there is *no way* to do this securely, so they should provide *something*.  If private docker hub credentials are all you've got, then you can use your private docker repository, but I wouldn't be super comfortable relying on their security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle allows you to configure environment variables per environment, and they are treated the same way environment variables on your local machine would be treated. This means you can configure for example, the SENDGRID_API_KEY variable, set it in Cycle to your API key (Navigate to Environments -> Container -> Config) and have your code read that variable directly.

You can declare environment variables that exist in your dockerfile (`ENV SENDGRID_API_KEY=""`), and Cycle will pre-populate those so that you can just fill in the box and hit save. You'll need to restart the container, but then your variables should be available to your program without you having to manage moving files around.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!